# Which order should one to retopologize?

Tags: retopology

So I'm sculpting a character for the first time and I wanted to ask what the next step would be, retopologizing with or without clothes? Or something different?

Does it matter? if i retopologized the body first and the the clothes over that, would that be a problem?

Comment: I guess it depends on your final goal, if it's for animation you probably need the clothes to be separated from the body

Comment: I just wanna pose it and make a turntable, if I were to retopogize clothes seperately, would i have to delete the retopology/mesh where the body under the clothes is? Or can I just have those double layers? :-)

Comment: if you choose to separate the clothes, you don't have to model the part of the body that is hidden by the clothes, if that's your question.